# ListView: grouping items by section

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

Taking for example **Gmail App**, on my `Navigation Drawer`, I want a `ListView` that is grouped by section, similar to **inbox, all labels**.

Is this behavior achieved by using multiple `ListView` separated by a "header" `TextView` (which I have to build manually obviously), or is this section-grouped behavior supported by the `Adapter` or `ListView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use multiple ListViews, it will mess things up for the scroll.

What you describe can be achieve by using only one ListView + adapter [with multiple item view types](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    // It's very important that the first item have a value of 0.
    // If not, the adapter won't work properly (I didn't figure out why yet)
    private int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 0;
    private int TYPE_DATA = 1;

    class Separator {
        String title;
    }

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (getItem(position).getClass().isAssignableFrom(Separator.class)) {
            return TYPE_SEPARATOR;
        }
        return TYPE_DATA;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // Assuming you have only 2 view types
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        // Mark separators as not enabled. That way, the onclick and onlongclik listener
        // won't be triggered for those items.
        return getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_SEPARATOR;
    }
}
```

You just have to implement your own [getView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method for a correct rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly how the Gmail app achieves this behavior, but it seems as though you should work on a custom adapter. Using multiple list views would not be a productive way to approach this problem, as one wants to keep the rows of data (messages) together in single list items.

Comment: I see. I'm using Model classes to fill the `ListView`, so I want to avoid doing *hack-ish* things like using an `interface` to add a `isHeader()` method to all of my Model classes.